# How can I join very thin sheets at a right angle?

Tags: joinery

I want to build a spice shelf organizer, something like this, out of thin bamboo sheets:

[image]

The bamboo sheets that I've got are actually leftover multi-ply flooring from another project, and are probably about 1/8" to 1/4" thick. The structural requirements (holding some spice bottles) aren't that extreme.

How could this kind of wood be joined in this way for this application?

Comment: *"probably about 1/8" to 1/4" thick"* Which is it? Please measure rather than giving an estimate. Well-done reinforced butt joints could be enough; you could reinforce with tiny brads or bamboo skewers, but I think this is only really feasible if the boards are 1/4". If they're on the thinner end of your estimate you should think about adding sides of some kind. If everything is done well it's possible that plain butt joints will be okay given the strength requirements here aren't huge, although you'd have to worry about careless handling and a drop to the floor could break one apart.

Comment: How are you fixed tooling-wise, is making grooves or rebates doable for you? If so you could try to design around those since they'll add noticeably to final strength (more so at the thicker end obviously). At the thinner end, do you have enough material that you could double up? Done this way some joinery can be built-in, rather than having to be a milling operation, if the accurate cutting/sizing wouldn't be too much effort.

Comment: Let me take an exact measurement, so I can give the most accurate information here.

Answer (score 2):

One easy option is to perhaps put two small (maybe 1/4" x 1/4" or so) runners on the back side to act as reinforcement for the joints, then use glue and/or small nails or staples or tiny countersunk screws. Something like this:

[image]

The bottom panel is extended past the larger panel a bit to give a surface to attach the runner to.

Comment: Hey, long time!

Comment: @JasonC: ooh, that's pretty clever.

Answer (score 1):

My drawing skills fail me atm, but if you put two sides on that idea, glued butt joints would almost certainly work. Bonus points if you put a block attached to each side, supporting the underside of the high end of the ramp.

If there was finish on the scrap pieces, you'd want to sand that off.

Epoxy would be my first choice, but I think that even a regular wood glue would work.